# Using simple_form to add association between two tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, simple-form

but for some reason the `manufacturer_id` column is not being populated when I create a new car and specify a manufacturer.  I want the `manufacturer_id` column in the `cars` table to be populated with the associated id.

My form for Manufacturer:

```
  <%= simple_form_for @manufacturer do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :country %>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Add Manufacturer"  %>
  <% end %>
```

My form for Car:

```
  <%= simple_form_for @car do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :color  %>
    <%= f.input :year  %>
    <%= f.input :mileage  %>
    <%= f.input :description  %>
    <%= f.association :manufacturer %>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Add Car"  %>
  <% end %>
```

The `<%= f.association :manufacturer %>` above correctly creates a dropdown menu with all manufacturers that I have added. My Car and Manufacturer models:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :manufacturer
end
```

and

```
class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars, dependent: :nullify
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh shoot I got it...simple enough solution. Just needed to change my permissions

```
  def car_params
    params.require(:car).permit(:color, :year, :mileage, :description, :manufacturer_id)
  end
```